# Call function every full hour

Tags: jquery

I want to call a jquery function every full hour.
So 11:00, 12:00, 13:00 etc.

Here is the function:

```
function flipIt() {
    $('#flip').addClass('animate pulse');
    $('#flip').removeClass('animate pulse').delay(1500);
}
```

How can I call it every full hour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do :

```js
setInterval(function(){
  
  if(new Date().getMinutes() === 0) {
    flipIt()
  }
},60000)

// for testing
setInterval(function(){
  if(new Date().getSeconds() === 0) {
    alert("new minute !");
  }
},1000)

function flipIt() {
    $('#flip').addClass('animate pulse');
    $('#flip').removeClass('animate pulse').delay(1500);
}
```

Comment: I forgot one `0`, it's `60000` (one minute), each minutes it check if this is a new hour (minutes = 0),`flipIt()` is then called only one time every hours on `xx:00`

Answer (score 1):

Solution which only triggers once per hour:

```
function alertNextHour() {
    var nextAlert = new Date();
    nextAlert.setHours(nextAlert.getHours() + 1);
    nextAlert.setMinutes(0);
    nextAlert.setSeconds(0);
    nextAlert.setMilliseconds(0);

    var timeToNextAlert = nextAlert - new Date();

    setTimeout(function() {
        // do what you want

        alertNextHour();
    }, timeToNextAlert);    
}
```

Comment: `setInterval` => `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which depends on a dynamic interval. The following function will set the timeout depending on how much time is left to the full hour:

```
function getDelay(){
    var date = new Date();
    var hour = date.getMinutes();
    return (60 - hour) * 60 * 1000; //get the milliseconds until the next full hour
}

delay = getDelay();
var dynamicInterval = function(){
    clearInterval(interval); //stop the current interval
    delay = getDelay();
    interval = setInterval(dynamicInterval, delay); //set the new interval with the new delay
}
var interval = setInterval(dynamicInterval, delay); //initial start of the interval
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h43v3wyw/)**

Note: the demo deals with seconds instead of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function
}, 3600000);
```

Comment: But that calls the function every hour, starting when the user hits the page and not every **full** hour, right?